# C/C++ Eclipse GDB not showing break points

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gdb

When I am trying to debug code in Eclipse it appears to run the debugger and stop but Eclipse is unable to find the source? A tab opens up that says "main() at 0x100000f64" with a button that says "view disassembly"

I can view the disassembly just fine but would be nice if I could get breakpoints working.
Thanks!

My Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int n = 10;
   int factorial = 1;

   // n! = 1*2*3...*n
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      cout << "i is " << i << endl;
      factorial *= i;
   }
   cout << "The Factorial of " << n << " is " << factorial << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

GDB warning  output:

```
warning: `/var/folders/s1/dxx9glzn45j6x2ypzk9xkjnc0000gp/T/Test-203d73.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
$1 = 0xff
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Symbols/BuiltProducts/libsystem_kernel.a"
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/_libc_funcptr.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/kernel_vers.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/memcpy.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strcmp.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlcpy.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.110.17~1/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlen.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libatomics_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libcachecontrol_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-4.90.1~2/Symbols/libos_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libsetjmp_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libsimple_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libstring_normal.a"
warning: Could not open OSO archive file "/BinaryCache/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/Symbols/libucontext_normal.a"
warning: `/private/var/tmp/libplatform/libplatform-24.90.1~2/libplatform.build/libsystem_platform.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/init.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.

Temporary breakpoint 2, 0x0000000100000f64 in main ()
Single stepping until exit from function main,
which has no line number information.
Single stepping until exit from function start,
which has no line number information.
[Inferior 1 (process 84739) exited normally]
Quit
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out too.. The issue was that when you create the project you need to make sure it's using Mac GCC not llvm to compile. Currently it seems you can't debug with gdb if you compiled with llvm :)

Comment: I installed g++-5, but there are more warning information when I call "r" in gdb. Quite weird and inconvenience.